# How can I add a property to a library that uses its own interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, gridster, angular-gridster2

I am using the angular-gridster2 package, and I want girdsterItem to have two more properties in its interface to store those values. How can I do it? Since in their code they use their own property no matter how much I create an extended interface of theirs and use that one.

```
export interface GridsterItemCustomInterface extends GridsterItemComponentInterface {
  property1?: boolean;
  property2?: Config;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypeScript module augmentation to extend the existing interface.

```
import { GridsterItemComponentInterface } from 'angular-gridster2';

// Augment the module with the extended interface
declare module 'angular-gridster2' {
  interface GridsterItemComponentInterface {
    property1?: boolean;
    property2?: Config;
  }
}

// Now you can use it with the additional properties
export interface GridsterItemCustomInterface extends GridsterItemComponentInterface {
  property1?: boolean;
  property2?: Config;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it! And is there a possibility to also somehow edit a method of yours to save that information?
https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2/blob/e081e2e95364098f9efaaa4fb96ab22e9a8f4dbf/projects/angular-gridster2/src/lib/gridsterItem.component.ts#L182

  itemChanged(): void {
 //add a line here, for example:
this.ConfigManagementService.itemChanged(this.item);

Comment: Don't change custom package code, unless you have a good reason to do it. But for what you asking I think you could just bind on itemChange which is an `Output()` of the component `GridsterItemComponent`.
`<gridster-item (itemChange)="callYourOwnMethod()"> </gridster-item>`